# Saving to external storage

Tags: android, android-studio, storage

I understand now that the "external storage" does not have to be a SDcard but is referred to another area of storage that the phone allocates to "external" as opposed to "internal".

My problem now creating the directory for my app. When I am compiling in Android Studio using a Nexus 5 emulator, my app crashes and the error is (after creating a log) `Failed to create directory`.

I already added permissions and still have difficulty. I added a breakpoint to the code right before the directory is made and receive the following:

sdcard/storage
Pictures/Appname (I am using the pictures directory)

After I see those strings in my logcat, it wont create the directory. Here is the code block that I am using:

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "AppName");

if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdir())
        Log.d("AppName", "failed to create directory");
    return null;
}
```

Can anyone steer me towards me the right direction? Thank you!

---

EDIT:

I added a check external storage :

```
public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and it returns false! I ran this before I input the code above. Any ideas?? I added the permissions (write external) and it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a class Save.java that does all my picture saving for me and this is the part I create a directory:

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ NameOfFolder;
File dir = new File(file_path);

if(!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

The class is temporary available with [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrgb6dfjgd3x6f5/Save.java?dl=0)

I call the class like this:

```
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.LoadingCarImageView);
    imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b = imageview.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b);
    Save savefile = new Save();
    savefile.SaveImage(this,  bitmap, "stream");
```

Tell my if this helped you!

Comment: That would be great if you dont mind! I've been trying to find a standard solutions to some of my problems but there are multiple solutions I don't understand fully.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mkdir(), which only creates one (last) directory. mkdirs() would also create any parent directories that could possibly be missing.

Comment: ah I see. so it is possible i am missing the parent directories?

Comment: That could be the problem. On a new device, such as a newly created Emulator image, the directory for Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES might not yet exist.

Comment: I added a test function and it returns false when I am checking if there is an external storage.  :X